# Setting up git after fresh install

Tags: macos, git, ssh, repository, ssh-keys

I'm planning to install mountain lion on my macbook pro and erase everything in my hard drive too. I currently have git installed with a few repos and my ssh key is connected with remote repos as well. I'm not sure how to go about restoring everything after the fresh install of osx. I am not very proficient with git so i might need a lot of help here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making a backup of the **complete** current harddrive for security reasons.

For SSH-Access to other repos you should keep your `~/.ssh/id_rsa[.pub]` file at hand, as that is the key to identify yourself at other repos (ssh-servers that is)

The repos should be backed up obviously.

After a fresh install you have to install git, add the `~/.ssh/id_rsa[.pub]` Files and then you should be and running.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you create a Time Machine backup before wiping the hard drive. Then after the update, use Time Machine to restore your user data and your local repos.

Before the update, I would create a list of the repos that you want to keep and add the remote URLs to the list. In case the Time Machine restore isn't able to restore everything, you could still `git clone` the missing repos.

I expect that Time Machine should cover most of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I have never tried to backup using Time Machine, I guess this is the time I should try it out.

Comment: Please let us know if this worked for you. And please upvote/accept the answers if it helped you.

Comment: ,@heighlandreas: finally did the fresh install, git works fine locally, but my remote is not allowing access even if i put back my keys in the ssh folder already. did i miss something?